# Fedora 37 hotspot not working

Tags: linux, fedora, wifi-hotspot

I am having trouble with the fedora 37 hotspot. I am uing a LAN network in my laptop and sharing my internet using fedora hotspot. Earlier it used to work properly but recently I am facing this problem of (connected..unable to provide internet). I have checked with other mobile devices but the problem exists in my fedora.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

On my setup, I had to disable Protected Management Frames:

```
nmcli connection down Hotspot
nmcli connection modify Hotspot 802-11-wireless-security.pmf 1
nmcli connection up Hotspot
```

Here are the upstream issue reports if you want to dig more into it:

- [Can't connect to hotspot created on ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1972790)
- [Can't connect to Network Manager's hotspot from Android - Timed Out / Obtaining IP address](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/841)

See also: [Unable to connect with the hotspot created on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424633/unable-to-connect-with-the-hotspot-created-on-ubuntu).